# XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/test.php. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

`XMLHttpRequest` cannot load `http://example.com/test.php.` No `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is present on the requested resource. Origin `http://eample.com` is therefore not allowed access.

How to resolve it. i added following headers in that php file:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, 
Authorization, X-Request-With');

header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
```

i replace my domain name 'codeXXX' with 'example' dont confuse with that

Comment: you have to add CORS support in server config, more details on CORS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: @Nemani it looks like Venkata has done that

Comment: Make sure this is right at the top of your `.php` script so that nothing it output before these headers are sent

Comment: Also, check your browser's *Network* console. is there an `OPTIONS` request? What do the response headers look like for the failed request?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson this does not appear to be a duplicate as OP appears to have made the correct server-side changes

Comment: @Phil It depends. The link about CORS in that answer has _a lot_ of information about different situations (including OPTIONS request). Might be some valid info in there.

Answer (score 1):

The header

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
```

MUST be given in response to an OPTION request to "http://example.com/test.php". If OPTION request contains this header, the following GET (or POST) will be accepted.

If the browser says that the header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is not present, ... just add it ^_^

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With');
```

Comment: I feel like OP would have a different error message if the server weren't responding correctly to an `OPTIONS` request.

Comment: And the OP actually have `OPTIONS` in the allowed methods, you don't ?

Comment: You have two request. First one is OPTION that tells to your client how can be the second.

Comment: ANY time you make a request with angular, the request is preceded by an OPTION request.

Comment: @sensorario that's not correct. A standard `GET` request without authorization will be *simple* and not require a pre-flight request. A `POST` request using `Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is also excempt